# QueryDefs Field Count not counting correctly

Tags: vba, ms-access, field, crosstab

I have several crosstab queries that I need to count the number of fields in. The previously working code had no issues.  Since, then, I've added parameters (looking up values on an open form) to the crosstab, but no other changes.  There are no errors, but the code returns field count = 0.  ??  It was working flawlessly beforehand.  Again, the only change I made is to replace a hard-coded date in the crosstab with a form reference, and added the parameter so the crosstab can be dynamic.  The query opens fine with no errors, so I'm stumped why this change would make a difference.

One other thing I have noted is that the c in ".Count" at the end of the line of code updates to a lower case c (.count) after I advance to the next line.  I would expect this to remain a capital letter.  This is a work computer, and it went through a lot of software updates yesterday.  Is this possibly a library issue?

```
`dim n, m, p, q, a as Integer

n = db.QueryDefs("Master_Schedule_Demand_Xtab").Fields.count   
m = db.QueryDefs("Production_Schedule_Future_Xtab").Fields.count   
p = db.QueryDefs("Production_Schedule_PRIOR_Xtab").Fields.count   
q = db.QueryDefs("Supplier_Committed_Del_Xtab").Fields.count   
a = db.QueryDefs("Actual_Receipts_Xtab").Fields.count `
```

No errors, just all values = 0 ?? I expect the values all to be >10 to match the number of fields/columns in the crosstab.
Also - the results of running code to get all query defs show as follows - field count isn't listed?!

```
`Properties of Master_Schedule_Demand_Xtab
 Name - Master_Schedule_Demand_Xtab
 DateCreated - 10/17/2019 2:49:32 PM
 LastUpdated - 10/18/2019 4:00:18 PM
 Type - 16
 SQL - PARAMETERS Forms!Main!MB51_Created DateTime;
TRANSFORM Sum(PO_List1_MstrSched.Scheduled_qty_) AS Qty
SELECT PO_List1_MstrSched.Material, "Master Schedule Demand" AS Type,
PO_List1_MstrSched.Short_text AS Material_Desc
FROM PO_List1_MstrSched
WHERE (((PO_List1_MstrSched.StatDelD)<#10/12/2020#))
GROUP BY PO_List1_MstrSched.Material, "Master Schedule Demand",
PO_List1_MstrSched.Short_text
PIVOT PO_List1_MstrSched.Week;

  Updatable - True
  Connect - [empty]
  ReturnsRecords - True
  ODBCTimeout - 60
  RecordsAffected - 0
  MaxRecords - 0
  RecordLocks - 0
  RecordsetType - 0
  Orientation - 0
  DefaultView - 2
  PublishToWeb - 1
  OrderByOn - False
  DisplayViewsOnSharePointSite - 1
  TotalsRow - False
  FilterOnLoad - False
  OrderByOnLoad - True
  HideNewField - False
  BackTint - 100
  BackShade - 100
  ThemeFontIndex - -1
  AlternateBackThemeColorIndex - -1
  AlternateBackTint - 100
  AlternateBackShade - 100
  ReadOnlyWhenDisconnected - False
  DatasheetGridlinesThemeColorIndex - -1
  DatasheetForeThemeColorIndex - -1`
```

Comment: Not familiar with VBA but here are few suggestions - (a) Does it start working if you revert back to the original code? (b) Can you print output of the original format versus the new one for one of the fields ? That will help you identify some gaps if any.

Comment: No! I have reverted back to original format and it still does not capture the field count.  It says zero which I believe is the default for not finding it.

Comment: Then perhaps there truly is no data or something linked to data-access has failed. You could try accessing the data source using a proof-of-concept / standalone program and validate data access first. Then you can try figuring out what is wrong in the code.

Comment: Is the referenced form (`Main`) open in FormView when running your code? And does the control `MB51_Created` contain a valid datetime value? The number of fields will of course depend on that parameter value.

Comment: Yes! Form is open. But I’ve even removed the variable and reverted back to the hard-coded filter and I have the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

Access doesn't attempt to determine `Fields.Count` for a cross-tab `QueryDef` which includes a `PARAMETERS` declaration.

For example, the `WHERE` clause in this query gives me 4 distinct values for `q.Options_Value` ...

```sql
TRANSFORM Count(*) AS Expr1
SELECT q.PersonName
FROM qryStep1 AS q
WHERE q.Options_Value <= 5
GROUP BY q.PersonName
PIVOT q.Options_Value;
```

So the `QueryDef.Fields.Count` shows me 5 (`PersonName` plus the 4 columns for the distinct `Options_Value` values).

However if I simply declare a parameter, which is not even referenced by the remainder of the SQL ...

```sql
PARAMETERS upper_limit Long;
TRANSFORM Count(*) AS Expr1
SELECT q.PersonName
FROM qryStep1 AS q
WHERE q.Options_Value <= 5
GROUP BY q.PersonName
PIVOT q.Options_Value;
```

Access apparently decides it can't know the number of columns when a parameter is involved.  And in that case it shows me zero for `QueryDef.Fields.Count`.

I'll suggest you get the query's column count by opening a recordset from the query and getting the recordset's `Fields.Count` like this ...

```vb
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set db = CurrentDb
Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("YourQueryName")
Set rs = qdf.OpenRecordset
Debug.Print "Query columns: " & rs.Fields.Count
```

Although your SQL sample declared the form reference as a `PARAMETER` it wasn't actually used in the rest of the query.  However when you do call `OpenRecordset` on a query which contains a form reference, Access will treat it as a parameter for which you have not supplied a value.  In that case, supply the value like this before calling `OpenRecordset` ...

```vb
qdf.Parameters("Forms!Main!MB51_Created").Value = Forms!Main!MB51_Created.Value
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the information.  You gave me enough information to begin my research and edit the code.  I now understand that there were 2 parameters being called (1 for the top level query, and one in the query being called).  I assigned both parameters explicitly in the code and then used Wolfgang's code below to get the field count.  Fingers crossed it still works next week!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to set the value of the parameter and open a recordset to be able to count the fields, for example for you first query:

```
With db.QueryDefs("Master_Schedule_Demand_Xtab")
    .Parameters("Forms!Main!MB51_Created") = Forms!Main!MB51_Created
    With .OpenRecordset(dbOpenDynaset, dbAppendOnly)
        n = .Fields.Count
        .Close
    End With
    .Close
End With
```

And as for the 'c': check all declarations of variables and constants or late-bound properties *count* written with a lowercase 'c' and change them to uppercase or (for variables and constants) rename them to something different.

Comment: THIS WORKED! Thank you!  I need to explicitly assign 2 parameters (both for top-level ad underlying query), then using your example, I was able to get the field count.  I have never worked with parameters before, so this has been a learning experience.  It also explains the "unexplainable" crosstab failures I've experienced in the past.  Thanks again!

Comment: @AngieHudsonGallegos, Glad to hear that! :-)